# What is another way to write the equation in the form $A x + B y + C z + D = 0$ where A > 0 and GCD[A,B,C,D]=1?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, geometry

I am trying write the equation of the plane passing through a point $A(x0, y0, z0)$ and take vector $w(A,B,C)$ as a normal vector. The equation has the form
$$A(x-x0) + B(y-y0) + C(z-z0)=0.$$
I would like to write the equation in the form
$$A x + By + C z + D=0$$
so that:

1. $GCD[A, B, C, D] = 1$ and $A>0$ if $A \neq 0$;
2. $GCD[B, C, D] = 1$ and $B > 0$ if $A = 0$;
3. $GCD[C, D] = 1$ and $C > 0$ if $A = B =  0$.

Some examples:

```
pA = {1, 2, 3};
w = {-2, 4, 6};
k = GCD[w[[1]], w[[2]], w[[3]]];
m = {x, y, z};
If[w[[1]] != 0, n = Sign[w[[1]]] w/k, 
  If[w[[2]] != 0, n = Sign[w[[2]]] w/k, 
   If[w[[3]] != 0, n = Sign[w[[3]]] w/k]]];
TraditionalForm[Expand[n . (m - pA)]] == 0
```

> x-2 y-3 z+12==0

```
pA = {1, 2, 3};
w = {0, -5, 10};
k = GCD[w[[1]], w[[2]], w[[3]]];
m = {x, y, z};
If[w[[1]] != 0, n = Sign[w[[1]]] w/k, 
  If[w[[2]] != 0, n = Sign[w[[2]]] w/k, 
   If[w[[3]] != 0, n = Sign[w[[3]]] w/k]]];
TraditionalForm[Expand[n . (m - pA)]] == 0
```

> y-2 z+4==0

```
pA = {0, 0, 0};
w = {0, -4, 2};
k = GCD[w[[1]], w[[2]], w[[3]]];
m = {x, y, z};
If[w[[1]] != 0, n = Sign[w[[1]]] w/k, 
  If[w[[2]] != 0, n = Sign[w[[2]]] w/k, 
   If[w[[3]] != 0, n = Sign[w[[3]]] w/k]]];
TraditionalForm[Expand[n . (m - pA)]] == 0
```

> 2 y-z=0

What is another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FactorList[w . (vars - pA)][[-1, 1]] == 0` works if the ordering of the variables respected the standard ordering.

*1.* The coefficient of `x` is positive but not `y`:

```
pA = {1, 2, 3};
w = {-2, 4, 6};
vars = {x, y, z};

FactorList[w . (vars - pA)][[-1, 1]] == 0

(* 12 + x - 2 y - 3 z == 0 *)
```

*2.* The coefficient of `y` is positive but not `z`:

```
pA = {1, 2, 3};
w = {0, -4, 6};
vars = {x, y, z};

FactorList[w . (vars - pA)][[-1, 1]] == 0

(* 5 + 2 y - 3 z == 0 *)
```

*3.*

```
pA = {1, 2, 3};
w = {0, 0, -6};
vars = {x, y, z};

FactorList[w . (vars - pA)][[-1, 1]] == 0

(* -3 + z == 0 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global*"];

f[pA_List, 
  w_List] := (Sign@FirstCase[w, Except[0]] w/GCD @@ w) . ({x, y, z} - 
      pA) == 0 // Expand
```

Supplied `PA` and `w` values for the three cases:

```
planes = {
  {{1, 2, 3}, {-2, 4, 6}}
  , {{1, 2, 3}, {0, -5, 10}}
  , {{0, 0, 0}, {0, -4, 2}}
  }

(* Could be done this way *)

g2 = f @@@ planes // 
  ContourPlot3D[#, {x, -2, 0}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 8}] &

(* Built-in Mathematica way *)

g1 = Hyperplane[#2, #1] & @@@ planes // Graphics3D[#, Axes -> True] &

Show[g1, g2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can build a `planeEquation` function as follows:

```
planeEquation[pA_List, w_List, m_List] := 
 Module[{k, n, nonZeroPos},
         k = GCD @@ w;
         nonZeroPos = Flatten[Position[w, Except[0], 1, Heads -> False]];
         n = If[Length[nonZeroPos] > 0, Sign[w[[First[nonZeroPos]]]] w/k, 
               ConstantArray[0, Length[w]]];
  TraditionalForm[Expand[n . (Sort@m - pA)]] == 0]

  planeEquation[{1, 2, 3}, {-2, 4, 6}, {x, y, z}]

  (*x-2 y-3 z+12==0*)

  planeEquation[{1, 2, 3}, {0, -5, 10}, {x, y, z}]

  (*y-2 z+4==0*)

  planeEquation[{0, 0, 0}, {0, -4, 2}, {x, y, z}]

  (*2 y-z==0*)
```