# How can I write the equations of the tangent plane to the sphere at all points in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
list = {x, y, z} /. 
  Solve[{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z + 3)^2 == 7^2}, {x, y, z}, 
   Integers]
```

> {{-6, 2, -3}, {-5, -1, -5}, {-5, -1, -1}, {-5, 0, -6}, {-5, 0,
> 0}, {-5, 4, -6}, {-5, 4, 0}, {-5, 5, -5}, {-5,
> 5, -1}, {-2, -4, -5}, {-2, -4, -1}, {-2, 0, -9}, {-2, 0, 3}, {-2,
> 4, -9}, {-2, 4, 3}, {-2, 8, -5}, {-2, 8, -1}, {-1, -4, -6}, {-1, -4,
> 0}, {-1, -1, -9}, {-1, -1, 3}, {-1, 5, -9}, {-1, 5, 3}, {-1,
> 8, -6}, {-1, 8, 0}, {1, -5, -3}, {1, 2, -10}, {1, 2, 4}, {1,
> 9, -3}, {3, -4, -6}, {3, -4, 0}, {3, -1, -9}, {3, -1, 3}, {3,
> 5, -9}, {3, 5, 3}, {3, 8, -6}, {3, 8,
> 0}, {4, -4, -5}, {4, -4, -1}, {4, 0, -9}, {4, 0, 3}, {4, 4, -9}, {4,
> 4, 3}, {4, 8, -5}, {4, 8, -1}, {7, -1, -5}, {7, -1, -1}, {7,
> 0, -6}, {7, 0, 0}, {7, 4, -6}, {7, 4, 0}, {7, 5, -5}, {7,
> 5, -1}, {8, 2, -3}}

At the point of contact, e.g `{-6, 2, -3}`,

I see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296065/what-is-another-way-to-write-the-equation-in-the-form-a-x-b-y-c-z-d-0/296070#296070), I tried

```
pC = {1, 2, -3};
pA = {-6, 2, -3};
pM = {x, y, z};
FactorList[(pA - pC) . (pM - pA)][[-1, 1]] == 0
```

> 6 + x == 0

How can I write the equation of all points in the `list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For pedagogical reasons I am showing one way that requires minor modification of your code.

```
pC = {1, 2, -3};
pM = {x, y, z};
pA = pM /. 
  Solve[{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z + 3)^2 == 7^2}, {x, y, z}, 
   Integers]
```

Then

```
Table[FactorList[(pA[[index]] - pC) . (pM - pA[[index]])][[-1, 1]] == 
  0, {index, 1, pA // Length}]
```

> [image: table]

Answer (score 4):

- When we set `f[x_, y_, z_] := (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z + 3)^2 - 7^2`, then the normal of the tangent plane is `Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]`.

```
Clear[f, list];
f[x_, y_, z_] := (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z + 3)^2 - 7^2;
list = Solve[f[x, y, z] == 0, {x, y, z}, Integers];
({X, Y, Z} - {x, y, z}) . Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0 /. 
  list // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The list of contact points and the center of the sphere are:

```
list = {x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z + 3)^2 == 7^2}, {x, y, z}, 
    Integers];
cen = {1, 2, -3};
```

Now, note that the vector from any point of the tangent plane to the point of contact is perpendicular to the radius of the sphere at the contact point. We therefore define a function, that gives the equation of the tangent plane at the contact point {x0,y0,z0} and apply it to the list:

```
tan[{x0_, y0_, 
    z0_}] = {x - x0, y - y0, z - z0} . ({x0, y0, z0} - cen) == 0;
tan /@ list // Simplify
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the output `Solve` in the way it was intended, the basic computational structure is this, with the use of `Hold` or `Inactivate` depending on the details of the problem:

```
<[held|inactive] code> /. Solve[eqns, vars] [// <[release|activate]>]
```

For instance:

```
pC = {1, 2, -3};
pA = {x0, y0, z0};
pM = {x, y, z};
gensol = Solve[{(x0 - 1)^2 + (y0 - 2)^2 + (z0 + 3)^2 == 7^2}, {x0, y0, z0}, 
   Integers];

Inactivate[FactorList[(pA - pC) . (pM - pA)][[-1, 1]] == 0] /. 
  gensol //
 Activate
(*
{6+x==0,            43+6 x+3 y+2 z==0, 31+6 x+3 y-2 z==0,
 48+6 x+2 y+3 z==0, 30+6 x+2 y-3 z==0, 56+6 x-2 y+3 z==0,
 38+6 x-2 y-3 z==0, 55+6 x-3 y+2 z==0, 43+6 x-3 y-2 z==0,
 40+3 x+6 y+2 z==0, 28+3 x+6 y-2 z==0, 60+3 x+2 y+6 z==0,
 24+3 x+2 y-6 z==0, 68+3 x-2 y+6 z==0, 32+3 x-2 y-6 z==0,
 64+3 x-6 y+2 z==0, 52+3 x-6 y-2 z==0, 44+2 x+6 y+3 z==0,
 26+2 x+6 y-3 z==0, 59+2 x+3 y+6 z==0, 23+2 x+3 y-6 z==0,
 71+2 x-3 y+6 z==0, 35+2 x-3 y-6 z==0, 68+2 x-6 y+3 z==0,
 50+2 x-6 y-3 z==0, 5+y==0,  10+z==0,  -4+z==0,  -9+y==0,
-48+2 x-6 y-3 z==0,-30+2 x-6 y+3 z==0,-63+2 x-3 y-6 z==0,
-27+2 x-3 y+6 z==0,-75+2 x+3 y-6 z==0,-39+2 x+3 y+6 z==0,
-72+2 x+6 y-3 z==0,-54+2 x+6 y+3 z==0,-46+3 x-6 y-2 z==0,
-34+3 x-6 y+2 z==0,-66+3 x-2 y-6 z==0,-30+3 x-2 y+6 z==0,
-74+3 x+2 y-6 z==0,-38+3 x+2 y+6 z==0,-70+3 x+6 y-2 z==0,
-58+3 x+6 y+2 z==0,-55+6 x-3 y-2 z==0,-43+6 x-3 y+2 z==0,
-60+6 x-2 y-3 z==0,-42+6 x-2 y+3 z==0,-68+6 x+2 y-3 z==0,
-50+6 x+2 y+3 z==0,-67+6 x+3 y-2 z==0,-55+6 x+3 y+2 z==0,
-8+x==0}
*)
```

Applying the output of `Solve` creates multiple copies of the held/inactive code, one copy for each set of parameter values in the solution. (The parameter values are the coordinates of the point `{x0, y0, z0}` in the example.) When the hold is released or the code activated, each code is evaluated with the parameter values already substituted. Usually, some parts of `<code>` need to be evaluated (e.g. `pA`) before the solution from `Solve` is applied, and some parts need to remain unevaluated (held or inactive). That can be tricky at times, but you learn how to do it with practice.

Alternatives to `Inactivate[FactorList[(pA - pC) . (pM - pA)][[-1, 1]] == 0]`:

```
Inactivate[FactorList[(pA - pC) . (pM - pA)][[-1, 1]] == 0, Part | FactorList]
With[{pA = pA}, Hold[FactorList[(pA - pC) . (pM - pA)][[-1, 1]] == 0]]
Hold[FactorList[({x0, y0, z0} - pC) . (pM - {x0, y0, z0})][[-1, 1]] == 0]
Hold[FactorList[(# - pC) . (pM - #)][[-1, 1]] == 0] &[pA]
Hold[FactorList[#][[-1, 1]] == 0 &][(pA - pC) . (pM - pA)]
```

For the ones using `Hold`, replace `Activate` by `ReleaseHold`:

```
<hold code> /. gensol // ReleaseHold
```

Or you can use `Table` or `Map` to iterate though the list of solutions, as the other answers show.  However, `ReplaceAll` does have this iteration capability built into it. So for pedagogical reasons, I wanted show it as well.