# How I can write the equation of the line as diameter of this circle?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this code.

```
ClearAll;
pI = {-1, -2};
pM = {x, y};
myr = 25;
list = {x, y} /. 
  Solve[{(x - pI[[1]])^2 + (y - pI[[2]])^2 == myr^2}, {x, y}, 
   Integers]
```

I want to write the equation passing through two points `pI` and all points of the list in the form A x + B y + C = 0 so that GCD[A, B, C]==1. How can I do this?

Comment: `Eliminate[{x == t  pI[[1]] + (1 - t) L[[1]], y == t  pI[[2]] + (1 - t) L[[2]]}, t]` will give you the equation of the line from pI to a point L. Also your `ClearAll;`  does nothing by the way - you should use `Remove["Global`*"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the  [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296065/what-is-another-way-to-write-the-equation-in-the-form-a-x-b-y-c-z-d-0?rq=1)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
pI = {-1, -2};
pM = {x, y};
myr = 25;
list = {x, y} /. 
   Solve[{(x - pI[[1]])^2 + (y - pI[[2]])^2 == myr^2}, {x, y}, 
    Integers];
Table[{u = pI - list[[i]];
  pM = {x, y};
  v = pM - list[[i]];
  d = Det[{u, v}]; list[[i]], 
  TraditionalForm[FactorList[d][[-1, 1]]] == 0}, {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

[image]